# twisted port synchronous code to async

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, deferred

I am trying to port my synchronous code to asynchronous, and I am stuck with this problem, here is the workflow:

- **creating a data object**: to this data I have to apply several actions, that depends on the result of the previous one (not for the result, but some action may be omitted)
- **Loop through all actions**
- **Check if the action needs to be applied**
- **Apply the action**
- **Return the data object altered**

Here what it could looks like in synchronous way:

```
import random

def list_actions():
    # this is a database query in real world
    return ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']

def apply_action(data, action):
    if random.randint(0, 1):
        data['applied_actions'].append(action)
    else:
        data['skipped_actions'].append(action)
    return data

def main():
    data = {
        'applied_actions': [], 
        'skipped_actions': []
    }
    actions = list_actions()
    for action in actions:
        apply_action(data, action)

    print data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

can someone point me to the right direction of making this code async ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are quite familiar with Twisted and asynchronous concepts such as: deferred, callback, errback, etc. What you need here is to deal with the for loop, you should use a [DeferredList](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.0.0/core/howto/defer.html#auto8) and that will do the trick.

Comment: the problem with DeferredList is that, in my case, I have to cancel all deferred if a certain code returns from one of them, so I don't want to wait for them all to finish all the time

Comment: nothing in your current synchronous code says you need to cancel the loop once you in a certain case, can you update it ?